# How to incorporate a tailor made function?

Tags: r

I have the following data (the data was melted via reshape2). The data looks like this. The name of the data is k.

```
 variable       value
 Revenue        23.34
 Revenue        34.44
 Revenue         13
```

I have written this piece of code to extract the first digit and last digit from value:

```
require(plyr)
require(stringr)
k <- ddply(k, .(variable), transform, 
           first.digit = str_extract(value, "[123456789]"),
           last.digit =   str_extract(value, "[[:digit:]]$"))
```

Maybe I need to try with this approach. To be sure to require all the libraries.

```
k_function <- function(data){
require(plyr)
require(stringr)
ddply(data, .(variable), transform, 
      first.digit = str_extract(value, "[123456789]"),
      last.digit =   str_extract(value, "[[:digit:]]$")) -> k_data
return(k_data)
}
```

After applying the code the data looks like this:

```
variable       value  first.digit  last.digit
 Revenue       23.34     2             4
 Revenue       34.44     3             4
 Revenue       13        1             3
```

How I can incorporate the whole procedure in tailor made function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work (you can read how to write functions for example here: http://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-write-and-debug-an-r-function/):

```
my_function <- function(data){

    ddply(data, .(variable), transform, 
          first.digit = str_extract(value, "[123456789]"),
          last.digit =   str_extract(value, "[[:digit:]]$")) -> new_data
    return(new_data)
}

my_function(k)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I do not understand what is the role of this part of the code   `-> new_data` and `return(new_data)`. Could you elaborate on this pls?

Comment: By `ddply()` I create a new dataframe, which I save as a local variable `new_data`. Function has this property, that it takes some values (`data` in our case) and returns one value (`new_data`) in our case. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes it is clear. Last but now least should I use always  this operator `->` to assign the new df?

Comment: You used it also in your question (`k <- ddply(...)`; you called it `k` then). What I did is a change of the order only (something like `ddply(...) -> k`). So, yes, you should use this operathor.

Comment: Now it is completely clear again a great thanks from my side. :)